# Do I need a transit visa for 23.5 hour layover in Dubai?

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, morocco

I'm a Moroccan passport holder traveling to Japan with a transit in Dubai.

My flight arrives at 22:30 in Terminal 1 and my connecting flight is on the next day at 22:05 in Terminal 3.

I intend to stay at the airport hotel in Terminal 3 because of the extremely long layover.

My question is: with a 23.5 hour layover from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3 the next day, do I need a Dubai transit Visa?

Answer (score 2):

You are eligible for [TWOV](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=MA&NV=Morocco&DC=JP&DV=Japan&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=3f24323065d599f16c98998d85389bb52a3d6395)

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

However, as noted in the comment below, it is a little too close for comfort. You should easily be able to get a [Transit visa for 96-hours](https://www.government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/types-of-visa#transit-visa-for-96-hours).

Comment: It's cutting it awful close. What if their inbound flight arrives early? I personally wouldn't risk it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas answer adjusted to indicate your concern. On a side-note thank you for granting a bounty to my other answer

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Who will notice? This rule is for airport check-in staff to enforce - immigration is not actively checking security cameras for how long a foreigner's staying in transit